# Global deep neural network with Tensorflow.keras in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am working on implementing an algorithm which approximates the solution of a partial differential equation. The main idea behind this is that I start at time 0 with a guess of the solution u[0], and its gradient z[0], and then use a recursive formula to approximately calculate the solution up to the last time point in a forward manner. The formula looks like this

```
u[i+1] = u[i] + f(t[i],x[i],u[i],z[i])*dt + z[i]*dW[i]
```

where the function f, time time discretization, the time step dt, and the increment of a Brownian motion dW is given. The gradient z[i] at time point i is being approximated by a deep neural network with input x[i] which I already have implemented with tf.keras with two hidden dense layers. These networks perform quite well. So far, I have N (number of time points) independent neural networks approximating z[i] for each time point respectively.

My task is to form a global neural network with input (x, W), and where (u[0], z[0]) will be given to this network as network parameters, such that this network can than optimize its parameters by minimizing the expected quadratic loss of the output/approximation of uN and the given terminal condition of the partial differential equation g(x). u[0] will then be the solution of the PDE. So while my neural networks approximating have 2 hidden layers each, the global network should have 2*(N-1) layers in total.

My neural networks for the gradients look like this:

```
# Input dimension
d = 1
# Output dimension
d_1 = 1
# Number of neurons
m = d + 10
# Batch size
batch_size = 32
# Training data
x_tr = some_simulation()
z_tr = calculated_given(x_tr)
# Test data
x_te = some_simulation()
z_te = calculated_given(x_te)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(d,), dtype=tf.float32))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(m, activation=tf.nn.tanh))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(m, activation=tf.nn.tanh))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(d_1, activation=tf.keras.activations.linear))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss='MeanSquaredError',
            metrics=[])
    model.fit(x_tr, z_tr, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=10)
    val_loss = model.evaluate(x_te, z_te)
    print(val_loss)
```

So I have trained N of them, and saved each as a file using

```
model.save(path_to_model)
```

So given the approximations of the gradients, I now want to stack all the subnetworks together to form a global deep neural network, which is based on the recursive formula above, which only takes the N-dimensional vectors x, and W as input data, and which gives the final output u[N] as output, and which uses (u[0], z[0]) as parameters. But I am trying to wrap my head around for two days as to how such a global neural network should be implemented in Python using Tensorflow.keras, so maybe someone can give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you'll pass the tuple `(x, dW, t)` as input to your model, since `t` is also indexed. Furthermore, you can always create `dW` from `W` using [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). I also assume that `u0` and `z0` are scalars (common to all batches).

With all of that in mind, you can [subclass](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_model_class) the base `Model` and override its `call()` as follows

```
class GlobalModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, u0, z0, dt, subnet_list, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.u0 = tf.Variable(u0, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.z0 = tf.Variable(z0, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.dt = tf.constant(dt, dtype=tf.float32)
        self.subnet_list = subnet_list

        # Freeze the pre-trained subnets
        for subnet in subnet_list:
            subnet.trainable = False  

    def f(self, t, x, u, z):
        # code of your function f() goes here

    def step_update(self, t, x, u, z, dW):
        return u + self.f(t, x, u, z) * self.dt + z * dW

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        x, dW, t = inputs
        # First step
        x_i = tf.gather(x, 0, axis=1)
        dW_i = tf.gather(dW, 0, axis=1)
        t_i = tf.gather(t, 0, axis=1)
        u_i = self.step_update(t_i, x_i, self.u0, self.z0, dW_i)

        # Subsequent steps
        for i, subnet in enumerate(self.subnet_list):
            x_i = tf.gather(x, i+1, axis=1)
            dW_i = tf.gather(dW, i+1, axis=1)
            t_i = tf.gather(t, i+1, axis=1)
            z_i = subnet(x_i, training=False)
            u_i = self.step_update(t_i, x_i, u_i, z_i, dW_i)

        return u_i
```

You initialize this model by

```
global_model = GlobalModel(init_u0, init_z0, dt, subnet_list)
```

where `subnet_list` is a list of your pre-trained subnets, ordered by time index. That is, the subnet responsible for predicting `z_i` should be at index `i-1` in this list.

After compiling, you call `fit()` on the model by

```
global_model.fit(x=(x_tr, dW_tr, t_tr), y=y_tr, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
```

where `y_tr` is your target.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! This looks very promising, and I didn't know that you can define tf.Variables as trainable objects. I will report later, once I have everything implemented.

Comment: You're welcome. I've just edited the subclassing snippet to make it proper (the old snippet was more like a skeleton). Please feel free to follow up in this comment if you encounter any difficulty using the updated snippet.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the trouble? Did you encounter errors using `tf.keras.models.load_model()` or were you lost on how to efficiently construct a list containing the models?

Comment: I am having trouble loading my saved models for the gradient at each timestep in a list:
`subnet_list = []
for i in range(1,N):
subnet_list.append(tf.keras.models.load_model(path/to/model))`

I get the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for models/test_model[1].model/variables/variables`
The path is correct, so I assume it is a problem that I use a native Python list for my models, since it cannot guess the datatype?

Comment: Python lists do not require elements to be of same type. This error is due to your not specifying the correct path to the saved model directory. You can checkout the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load). Also, did this error happen earlier prior to this question?

Comment: If I mess up the filepath I get a standard file not found error:
`OSError: No file or directory found at models/test_model\[1\].model`

But if I try to load from the correct path I get the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for models/test_model[1].model/variables/variables
 You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'.`

Comment: To be honest I don't see any reason why the loading doesn't work. Could be because of the square bracket in model filename. Have you tried loading your models prior to asking this question on SO, and did it work back then?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem! Thank you very much! Renaming the model solves the problem, and I can now properly load these. Now, I only need to rename 238 folders.

Comment: So, now when running my Python script, I get an value error at the line of `global_model.fit(x=(x_train, dW_train, t), y=term_con_tr, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)`.
It states: `ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'tuple'> containing values of types {'(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'numpy.ndarray\'>"})', '(<class \'list\'> containing values of types {"<class \'float\'>"})'}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.float64'>"})`, so something seems to be off with my input.

Comment: `x_train`, `dW_train`, `t` must all be *numpy arrays* with the same first dimension. The error suggests that your `x_train` is a *list* of numpy array, `dW_train` is a list of Python float, and `t` is a list of numpy float.

Comment: 'x_tr' is a list containing '300*batch_size' lists of length 'N'.
`dW_tr` is a list containing `300*batch_size` lists of length `N-1`.
`t_tr` is a list of length `N`, since it stays the same for every iteration of the whole number of simulations `300*batch_size*`. I have already adjusted the code, such that I now have `t_i = tf.gather(t, i)`.

Edit: `dW_train` is filled with calls of a function called `brownian_step(w, N)` for a Brownian motion `w`, and number of steps `N`. The value `dW` which will be returned by this function, is initialized by `dW = np.ones(N-1)`.

Comment: I don't actually understand why Python interprets floating point values differently, but is there a way to uniformly declare these lists?

Comment: You can't just pass list of list to fit(). You need to convert them to numpy array first. For example, if you have a list of 300*batch_size numpy arrays of shape (N,), then you can properly format `x_train` by `x_train = np.stack(list_of_np_arrays, axis=0)`. The resultant `x_train` should have shape of (300*batch_size, N). Do anything you can to get `dW_train` and `t_train` to a numpy array of shape (300*batch_size, N-1) and (300*batch_size, N), respectively. For starter, you can form a numpy array from `dW_train = np.array(dW_train)`.

Comment: Got it! Now I get an error regarding the argument `training=None` in the call function of the custom model class. The error states: `TypeError: outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call() got multiple values for argument 'training'`. Looking at the documentation, the call function is stated the same as in the chapter "Privileged training argument in the call() method", but without the `self` argument.

Comment: I did have self in call's arguments in the snippet. Did you forget to include it in your code? Or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341042/keras-subclassing-typeerror-tf-call-got-multiple-values-for-argument-traini) will help.

Comment: Maybe I was too tired yesterday or it was the heat, but I forgot to add self as in your snippet. So I added that, adjusted the code a little bit because of some minor errors I got, and now it is training through the epochs. But there is one problem, though: At `loss:` it says `nan`. I compiled the model with `adam` optimizer, and with `MeanSquaredError` as my loss function. Apparently, something is off here with the loss calculation.
I calculated the terminal condition using the n-th value of every `x` for each simulation and stored it in a np.stack as the other data with shape batch_size*300

Comment: I am not really familiar with differential equation so I can't say for sure how you're going about calculating the loss. If your loss is not simply just the MSE between the predicted `u_n` and the true `u_n`, then you may need to either write a custom loss function (which takes `y_true` and `y_pred` as arguments) or use the model's `add_loss()` API (in case the loss depends on factors other than `y_true` and `y_pred`), see [here](https://keras.io/api/losses/). There are also various techniques to stabilize training like gradient clipping, but that in itself is too wide to cover here.

Comment: It is pretty easy here: After recursively calculating u_N, the network should optimize its paramters (especially u_0) via minimizing the following mean squared error: `error = mse(u_N - g(x_N))`, where `g(x)` is the terminal condition in a sense that `u(t_N, x) = g(x)`. So the idea is that if `u_N` is very close to `g(x_N)`, then `u_0` is close to the true solution of the PDE. Therefore, I call `model.fit` with: `global_model.fit(x=(x_train, dW_train, t_train), y=term_con_tr, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)`, where `term_con_tr` is a list of `g(x_N)`.

Comment: If that's the case, you may want to lower the learning rate, or use a warm up phase at the beginning of training, or use gradient clipping to avoid divergence at early stages where the loss can be very high. You can print the predicted `u_n` in `call` using `tf.print(u_i)` and examine the early predictions. As for the techniques I mentioned, there are various resources on how to implement them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! I will study these techniques, and try to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Ok, now I think I narrowed the problem down. The network actually works, the problem is though that in order to minimize the loss, the network optimizes `u0` and `z0` "too" hard, such that these values get to `-nan`. I only got the  network once to give me a loss of around 0.65, instead of `nan` after 10 epochs. I am wondering if batch_normalization would be helpful here, but I have trouble finding a way to properly implement it into my model, such that I can try it out. So how would I do it? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how you are going to use batch norm in this network. Despite its name, BatchNorm purpose is to make the samples have zero mean and unit variance, not simply averaging the samples. I am not even sure using BN is appropriate in this context. Also, you can make a new question to avoid long discussion in comments.